# Extracting values from JSON Ajax return

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

PHP (processing.php):

```
$responce["x"] = 0;
$responce["y"] = [1, 3];
echo json_encode($responce);
```

javascript:

```
$.get("processing.php", function(data){
   alert("Data: " + data)
});
```

Output (alert):

```
Data: {"x":0,"y":["1","3"]}
```

I need to access the variable x, and the array y in javascript ?!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parse the JSON string with [`$.parseJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/).

Then, access `data.x`.

```
$.get("processing.php", function(data){
   data = $.parseJSON(data);
   var x = data.x;
});
```

Alternatively, you can set the `dataType` to `json` or use `$.getJSON()` which will automatically do it.

Comment: As a rule I set the `dataType` to `json` if I know that the data returned is always going to be jSON.

Answer (score 3):

According to your response Data: {"x":0,"y":["1","3"]}

```
$.get("processing.php", function(data){
    alert(data.x); // Will alert "0"
    alert(data.y[0]); // Will alert "1"
    alert(data.y[1]); // Will alert "3"
}, "json");
```

Answer (score 1):

With the jQuery.ajax Method you have the possibility to set the `dataType` attribute to `json`. Then you can have a function `success: function ( data ) { alert (data.x + data.y); }`. For more infos look at the documentation at your own.

**Edit:** [jQuery.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)() is what you are looking for... it is like the `jQuery.get` method  but parses the result to a javascript object.

Your code would than look like this:

```
$.getJSON("processing.php", function(data){
    var x = data.x;
    var y = data.y;
});
```